# ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `shorthands=off' for package `babeltools'

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am getting the below error. I am using MiKTex. Kindly help.

LaTeX Error: File `babeltools.sty` not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `shorthands=off` for package `babeltools`.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.171 \let
          \show\myoldshow\renewcommand{\myoldshow}{}  % re-enable \show command

Comment: Is babeltools installed or not? Fix the first

Comment: There's a warning in the first page of the documentation: `This package is deprecated. Use babel 3.9 and later instead.` Present version of babel is 3.33, though. I guess it's a simple typo).